# java GUI did not open after in IntelliJ

Tags: java

i try to run the GUI and the program opens but i can't see the window. After 10 seconds it closes again and gives this error:

--

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-17.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=49311:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath OverervingFiguren/target/classes presentatie.FiguurGUI

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:678)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:786)
    at presentatie.FiguurGUI.<init>(FiguurGUI.java:21)
    at presentatie.FiguurGUI.main(FiguurGUI.java:66)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

this is my Figuur GUI in the same package 'presentatie' as the form. i use code out of the package 'logica'. i use an enum and two classes 'Vierkant' and 'Cirkel'. The error on line 21 indicates to ' `int x = Integer.parseInt(TextxCoordinaat.getText());'`

line 66 is

```
frame.setContentPane(new FiguurGUI().FiguurGUI);
```

```
package presentatie;


public class FiguurGUI {
    private JTextField TextxCoordinaat;
    int x = Integer.parseInt(TextxCoordinaat.getText());
    private JTextField TextyCoordinaat;
    int y = Integer.parseInt(TextyCoordinaat.getText());
    private JComboBox<Kleur> comboKleur;
    Kleur kleur = Kleur.valueOf((String) comboKleur.getSelectedItem());
    private JComboBox<Kleur> comboKleurRand;
    Kleur kleurRand = Kleur.valueOf((String) comboKleurRand.getSelectedItem());
    private JRadioButton cirkelRadioButton;
    private JRadioButton vierkantRadioButton;
    private JButton voegToeButton;
    private JButton undoButton;
    private JSpinner SpinDikteRand;
    int dikteRand = (int) SpinDikteRand.getValue();
    private JTextField Textgrootte;
    double grootte = Double.parseDouble(Textgrootte.getText());
    private JPanel FiguurGUI;
    private JTextField TextOutput;
    private ArrayList<String> outputLijst = new ArrayList<>();


    public FiguurGUI() {
        voegToeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (cirkelRadioButton.isSelected()) {
                Cirkel cirkel = new Cirkel(new Punt(x, y), grootte, kleur, kleurRand, dikteRand);
                    outputLijst.add(cirkel.toString());
                    System.out.println("cirkel!!!");
                } if (vierkantRadioButton.isSelected()) {
                    Vierkant vierkant = new Vierkant(new Punt(x, y), grootte, kleur, kleurRand, dikteRand);
                    outputLijst.add(vierkant.toString());
                    System.out.println("vierkant!!!");
                } else {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Kies uit cirkel of vierkant");
                }

                TextOutput.setText(outputLijst.toString());

            }
        });

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("FiguurGUI");
        frame.setContentPane(new FiguurGUI().FiguurGUI);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(740, 440);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

I tried to run project with GUI and that worked perfectly so I don't know what the problem can be.

here is a picture how i organized the form:

[the form GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJnjN.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the text that you are trying to parse is empty so it cannot be parsed.

If you read source description of function parseInt(String s) you will see that it's clearly stated that each character inside must be a digit not counting first character which can be a minus sign.

quote

```
/**
 * Parses the string argument as a signed decimal integer. The
 * characters in the string must all be decimal digits, except
 * that the first character may be an ASCII minus sign {@code '-'}
 * ({@code '\u005Cu002D'}) to indicate a negative value or an
 * ASCII plus sign {@code '+'} ({@code '\u005Cu002B'}) to
 * indicate a positive value. The resulting integer value is
 * returned, exactly as if the argument and the radix 10 were
 * given as arguments to the {@link #parseInt(java.lang.String,
 * int)} method.
 *
 * @param s    a {@code String} containing the {@code int}
 *             representation to be parsed
 * @return     the integer value represented by the argument in decimal.
 * @exception  NumberFormatException  if the string does not contain a
 *               parsable integer.
 */
```